# Consuming a SOAP based web service in a Mule flow

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-flow

I am using Mule Studio to create a flow which will consume public webservice http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL&method=GetCityForecastByZIP. To achieve the same I have created the following configuration xml.

```html
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"     xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="Bean" name="Bean" class="javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext" factory-method="newInstance" doc:name="myJAXBCtx">
        <spring:constructor-arg value="com.practice.data"/>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="webservice" doc:name="webservice">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\MuleStudio\workspace\transformer\ip" moveToDirectory="D:\MuleStudio\workspace\transformer\processed" doc:name="Input Request File">
        <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="^.*\ws.(xml)$" caseSensitive="true"/>
    </file:inbound-endpoint>
    <mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer returnClass="com.practice.data.GetCityForecastByZIP" doc:name="XML to Object">
        <mulexml:alias name="GetCityForecastByZIP" class="com.practice.data.GetCityForecastByZIP"/>
    </mulexml:xml-to-object-transformer>
    <outbound-endpoint address="wsdl-cxf:http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL&amp;method=GetCityForecastByZIP" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="Generic"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\MuleStudio\workspace\transformer\output" outputPattern="ws-response#[function:dateStamp].xml" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

On running the flow in Mule Studio I get the following exception:

```java
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Marshalling Error: class com.practice.data.GetCityForecastByZIP nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

I have provided the GetCityForecastByZIP with the correct annotation. Refer code below:

```java
package com.practice.data;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="GetCityForecastByZIP",namespace="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "zip"})
public class GetCityForecastByZIP {

    @XmlElement(name="ZIP",required = true)
    private String zip =  null;

    public GetCityForecastByZIP() {

    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me how should I correct the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try just passing the zip to the service as input (the actual String i.e. 02111 for example instead of the XML).

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of the CXF WSDL connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/WSDL+Connectors#WSDLConnectors-GenericWSDLEndpoints) states:

> The one limitation of the CXF WSDL provider is that it does not allow
>   you to use non-Java primitives (objects that are not a String, int,
>   double, and so on).

GetCityForecastByZIP returns a complex object, not just a simple value, therefore you can not use the CXF WSDL connector to interact with this web service.

Instead, use a [CXF JAX-WS client](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Consuming+Web+Services+with+CXF).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with Mule web service consumer component :- `<ws:consumer-config/>` ?
Here is the reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Web+Service+Consumer